# Glimpse ADO fails in Web Site project with TableAdapters

Tags: ado.net, tableadapter, glimpse

I have **Glimpse ASP.NET** working in my ASP.NET WebSite project (.Net 4.0).

But when I try adding **Glimpse ADO** my project fails with multiple errors like this:

> *'Glimpse.Ado.AlternateType.GlimpseDbDataAdapter' is inaccessible due to its protection level*

The offending code is caused by generated App_Code.*.cs files, where it constructs the *TableAdapter classes. Here is an example of the generated code:

```
public partial class CallsSampleDataSetTableAdapter : global::System.ComponentModel.Component {

    private global::Glimpse.Ado.AlternateType.GlimpseDbDataAdapter _adapter;
    private global::Glimpse.Ado.AlternateType.GlimpseDbConnection _connection;
    private global::Glimpse.Ado.AlternateType.GlimpseDbCommand[] _commandCollection;
```

The **GlimpseDbConnection** and **GlimpseDbCommand** classes are accessible and do not cause an error, only the **GlimpseDbDataAdapater** line causes the error (along with accessor methods for this field).

Checking the [Glimpse ADO source code](https://github.com/Glimpse/Glimpse/blob/master/source/Glimpse.Ado/AlternateType/GlimpseDbDataAdapter.cs), the **GlimpseDbDataAdapter** class is indeed declared *internal*, and won't be accessible.

Should this class be made *public* in the **Glimpse ADO** library? Or is there something I can do to my TableAdapater .xsd files or code-behind to change the behavior of the code generator?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: I don't see a direct reason why we could not make the `GlimpseDbDataAdapter` public. Would you mind creating an issue in our [issue tracker](https://github.com/glimpse/glimpse/issues)?

Comment: I created [an issue](https://github.com/Glimpse/Glimpse/issues/438) for you on our [issue tracker](https://github.com/Glimpse/Glimpse/issues/) because we have a release coming up and might be able to include a fix with it.

Comment: We should be able to squeeze this into the next release. Track it over in this issue Chris has made.

Comment: Great, thanks. I'll flag answer once it's released and working ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class will be public as from version 1.4.1 of Glimpse.Ado

Comment: Fixed. However, new problem:

- The Glimpse.Ado.AlternateType.GlimpseDbCommand class needs a default constructor
- The Glimpse.Ado.AlternateType.GlimpseDbConnection class needs a constructor that takes a string (connectionString)
  (This second problem is strange, because the System.Common.DbConnection class does not have a constructor that takes a string either.)