# Glimpse ADO fails in Web Site project with TableAdapters - Part 2

Tags: ado.net, tableadapter, glimpse

This is a follow up to [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17438343/glimpse-ado-fails-in-web-site-project-with-tableadapters).

That problem was fixed. However, new compiler errors occurred. The compiler errors indicate the following:

- The **Glimpse.Ado.AlternateType.GlimpseDbCommand** class needs a default constructor
- The **Glimpse.Ado.AlternateType.GlimpseDbConnection** class needs a constructor that takes a string (connectionString)

  - *This second problem is strange, because the **System.Common.DbConnection** class does not have a constructor that takes a string either.*

Comment: Hi David, would you mind creating an issue for it on [our issue tracker](https://github.com/glimpse/glimpse/issues)? I think that would be a more appropriate place to discuss this, thanks

Comment: Thanks, done: https://github.com/Glimpse/Glimpse/issues/464